# STTwitter duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter, sttwitter

I am trying to integrate [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) library to get user tweets from Twitter using screen name. I have followed the instructions mentioned in that link. But when I build the app it fails because of linker issues and duplicate symbols as mentioned below.

duplicate symbol `_STTwitterOSErrorCode` in:

```
/Users/ramchadrareddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeitterTest-etwzglyyomuawtdbtjioroxrmyrr/Build/Intermediates/TeitterTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TeitterTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/STTwitterOS.o
/Users/ramchadrareddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeitterTest-etwzglyyomuawtdbtjioroxrmyrr/Build/Intermediates/TeitterTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TeitterTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/STTwitterAPI.o
```

duplicate symbol `_STTwitterOAuthErrorCode` in:

```
/Users/ramchadrareddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeitterTest-etwzglyyomuawtdbtjioroxrmyrr/Build/Intermediates/TeitterTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TeitterTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/STTwitterOAuth.o
/Users/ramchadrareddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeitterTest-etwzglyyomuawtdbtjioroxrmyrr/Build/Intermediates/TeitterTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TeitterTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/STTwitterAPI.o
```

duplicate symbol `_STTwitterAppOnlyErrorCode` in:

```
/Users/ramchadrareddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeitterTest-etwzglyyomuawtdbtjioroxrmyrr/Build/Intermediates/TeitterTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TeitterTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/STTwitterAppOnly.o
/Users/ramchadrareddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TeitterTest-etwzglyyomuawtdbtjioroxrmyrr/Build/Intermediates/TeitterTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TeitterTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/STTwitterAPI.o
```

ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

**clang: error:**

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can someone give me the solution for this.

Comment: Check in your project folder, seems like you have two copy of these three files

Comment: Hi pawan, no its not added twice. It doesn't has any duplicates also. Here is the dropbox link to project   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qdo5cqn72qlp6k7/AAD9Iv5bVTU1OkYxs942bPnFa?dl=0

Comment: How you installed this library, with cocoapods ?

Comment: no, i have download that library from github and added it to project.

Comment: check if you have imported the .m files by mistake instead of .h

Comment: I haven't imported any class. I just added the library and required frameworks. After that when I build the app its failing.

Comment: Have you added -ObjC in Other Linker Flags?

Comment: No Daljeet i have not added

Comment: Hey, I have deleted the library from my machine and from even trash. After that I have created new app and then tested the same. Now its working. But the old app still throws the error. Strange!! But I am not gonna  waste my time by  spending time to get  the solution for this weird case. Anyways, Thanks for your replies!!

Comment: Thats actually not strange. i have checked your code, STTwitter folder which you have added in project has only reference to the folder(not copied all files in folder). thats why when you are trying to compile the code, its getting two files, one from reference folder & one from project folder. Remove folder from your project & add it again (make sure you checked copy files in prompt). it will work fine>> "That actually is very common mistake"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, check if you have any of those files duplicated in your project's folder

Comment: I mean, maybe you already had a library and then add another library which has the first library inside

Comment: Even I felt the same, that's why I have created new app and then tested. But here also same error.

Comment: Here is the dropbox link to project in  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qdo5cqn72qlp6k7/AAD9Iv5bVTU1OkYxs942bPnFa?dl=0

Comment: Hey, I have deleted the library from my machine and from even trash. After that I have created new app and then tested the same. Now its working. But the old app still throws the error. Strange!! But I am not gonna  waste my time by  spending time to get  the solution for this weird case. Anyways, Thanks for your reply!!